# Graphics Gems IV. Binary Image Thinning Using Neigborhood Maps

Tags: c++, c, graphics, image-processing

What does this expression's algorithm mean?

```
p = ((p<<1)&0666) | ((q<<3)&0110) | (Image->scanLine(y+1)[x+1] != 0);
```

Algorithm "Binary Image Thinning Using Neigborhood Maps" in a book "Graphics Gems IV":

```
    static int  masks[] = {0200, 0002, 0040, 0010};

 uchar delete_[512] = 
 {
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,  0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,  0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1, 
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,  0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
 };

  int xsize, ysize; 
  int x, y; 
 int i;  
 int count = 1; 
 int p, q;  
 uchar *qb;
 int m;


 xsize = Image->width();
 ysize = Image->height();
 qb = (uchar*) malloc (xsize*sizeof(uchar));
 qb[xsize-1] = 0;

    while(count) 
 { 
  count = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
  {
   m = masks[i];
   p = Image->scanLine(0)[0] != 0;

   for (x = 0; x < xsize-1; ++x)
    qb[x] = p = ((p<<1)&0006) | (Image->scanLine(0)[x+1] != 0);

   // Scan image for pixel deletion candidates.
   for (y = 0; y < ysize-1; ++y) 
   {
    q = qb[0];
    p = ((q<<3)&0110) | (Image->scanLine(y+1)[0] != 0);

    for (x = 0; x < xsize-1; ++x) 
    { 
     q = qb[x];
     p = ((p<<1)&0666) | ((q<<3)&0110) | (Image->scanLine(y+1)[x+1] != 0);
     qb[x] = p;
     if  ((p&m)==0 && delete_[p])
     {
      count++;
      Image->scanLine(y)[x] = 0; 
     } 
    }
```

Comment: And now we see the importance of naming constants.

Comment: C programmers believe meaningful identitifer names lead to poor execution time:)

Comment: This line has a typo: `p = ((q<<3)&0110) | (Image->scanLine(y+1)[0] != 0);`  The `3` should be a `2`.  I think...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(See [commented source code](http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gemsiv/thin_image.c))

The variables `m`, `p`, `q`, and elements of the `qb` array are 9-bit numbers that represent the 3x3-pixel "neighborhood" of a pixel.

Suppose your image looks like this (each letter represents a pixel, which is either 'on' or 'off' (1 or 0, black or white):

```
    ---x---
    0123456
| 0 abcdefg
| 1 hijklmn
y 2 opqrstu
| 3 vwxyz{|
```

The pixel at (x,y) location (2,1) is `j`.  The neighborhood of that pixel is

```
bcd
ijk  // 3x3 grid centered on j
pqr
```

Since each pixel has a binary value, the neighborhood can be represented in 9 bits.  The neighborhood above can be written out linearly, expressed in binary as `bcd_ijk_pqr`.  The grouping of 3 pixels in a row makes octal a good choice, since each octal digit represents three bits.

Once you have a neighborhood expressed as a 9-bit value, you can do bit-manipulation on it.  An operation such as `((p << 1) & 0666)` takes a neighborhood, shifts all bits to the left one position, and clears the rightmost column of bits.  For example, the shift changes `bcd_ijk_pqr` to `cdi_jkp_qr@` (where `@` represents a 'null' bit, by default 0).  Then the mask changes it to `cd@_jk@_qr@`.  Expressed in 3x3 grid form:

```
cd@
jk@
qr@
```

Essentially, the whole grid has been shifted to the left.

Similarly, an operation such as `((q << 3) & 0110)` shifts all bits three positions (moves rows up) and clears the first two columns of bits.  So `bcd_ijk_pqr` becomes `ijk_pqr_@@@` and then after the masking, becomes `@@k_@@r_@@@`.

The gist of the algorithm is to evaluate the neighborhood of each pixel to determine whether to turn that pixel off (delete it).  This line does the evaluation:

```
if  ((p&m)==0 && delete_[p])
```

Everything that precedes that line is done to set up the neighborhood in `p`.  The code is written so that each pixel value is read exactly once per pass.

The `qb` array stores the neighborhood for each pixel in the previous scanline.  Note that the elements of `qb` are only 8-bits wide.  This means the upper-left pixel of the neighborhood is omitted.  That is not a problem, since any time `qb` is used, it gets shifted up a row.

So to answer your question about what this line does:

```
p = ((p<<1)&0666) | ((q<<3)&0110) | (Image->scanLine(y+1)[x+1] != 0);
```

It creates the neighborhood of a pixel by merging the following:

- the neighborhood of the previous pixel on the same line, shifted to the left
- the right column of the neighborhood of the pixel one row higher, shifted up
- the (x+1,y+1) pixel of the image, put into the "southwest" corner

For example, the neighborhood about `j` is calculated as:

```
p = bc@_ij@_pq@ | @@d_@@k_@@@ | r

    bc@ | @@d | @@@   bcd
p = ij@ | @@k | @@@ = ijk
    pq@ | @@@ | @@r   pqr
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bitwise manipulation. Do you not understand the individual operations, or do you not understand why *that* manipulation is being done (if the later, a link to a description of the algorithm is essential, BTW)?

[Operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Bitwise_operators) in that line:

- `<<` right shift operator (move the bits of p to more significant positions according to the RH argument)
- `&` in this context the bitwise and
- `|` the bitwise or

A helpful thing to recall here is that integer literals that start with '0' are expressed in *octal*  which means that you can read the binary digits right out of the on-screen representation (well, with a little practice, anyway). The constants here are (666)_8 = (110110110)_2 and (0110)_8 = (001001000)_2.

Comment: This manipulation is a mask 3x3 that walk along the image, but don't understand why that manipulation is being done)

Comment: @dmckee - you got the 0666 bit pattern wrong.  110110110 helps the OP see that it is the inverted bit pattern for 0110